# Rechazo app en IOS

Tags: ios

Hace unos días subí una aplicación para su aprobación a la consola de desarrolladores de Apple y me la rechazaron por lo siguiente (texto original en inglés):

> Guideline 4.2.2 - Design
>
> Thank you for your resubmission.
>
> We noticed that your app’s main functionality is to market your
>   service, with limited or no user-facing interactive features or
>   functionality. Apps that are primarily marketing materials or
>   advertisements are not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Next Steps
>
> We encourage you to review your app concept and incorporate different
>   content and features that are in compliance with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines.
>
> We understand that there are no hard and fast rules to define useful
>   or entertaining, but Apple and Apple customers expect apps to provide
>   a really great user experience. Apps should provide valuable utility
>   or entertainment, draw people in by offering compelling capabilities
>   or content, or enable people to do something they couldn't do before
>   or in a way they couldn't do it before.

¿Podríais indicarme cómo solucionar esto?

No alcanzo a entender cuál es el problema ya que el usuario no paga por esta app.

Les agradecería su ayuda ya que mi inglés es muy bajo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta de programación

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado: Creo que sí es válida. En el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) dice que es válido preguntar sobre "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores". Entiendo que sería este caso.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado A pesar de no ser una pregunta enfocada directamente a la programación es una pregunta que le podría ser útil a cualquier programador. No entiendo esa obsesión que tenéis algunos con que todas las preguntas deban llevar algo de código. El mundo de la programación abarca muchísimos temas y este es uno de ellos.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado ademas el propio usuario dice que su ingles es bajo por lo que no tiene tanta facilidad como para usar otros sitios mas especificos de stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AndoniAlda  No asocio la apple store como "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores", no se trata de que lleve código o no. De todas formas, veo complicado que se le pueda ayudar de forma efectiva, es demasiada amplia, no ha pasado el filtro de calidad y sin más información poco se le puede decir... Retiro el voto no obstante por lo primero que comento.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado Efectivamente es una pregunta demasiado amplia y que probablemente aquí no encuentre respuesta, aun así, en mi opinión si es un tema relacionado con la programación. Evidentemente no vamos a estar todos de acuerdo, ni los comentarios son el lugar para debatir sobre si están bien estas preguntas o no. Yo he reportado la pregunta como demasiado amplia, pero como he dicho bajo mi opinión si que tiene una relación con la programación.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino Concuerdo contigo, en que esta pregunta, aunque bien no versa sobre un problema de programacion, puede relacionarse con las herramientas de software, aunque en dicho caso, haria falta un poco mas de informacion por parte del usuario, ya que el problema planteado por el, refiere a un problema posiblemente en el diseño de la aplicacion, o que como tal, no tenga cabida en los Apple Human Guidelines, y por tanto sea el problema que el comenta.